# How is it possible to reset the same value of a key which appears in a array of objects using setState?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
{
id: 1,
value: "asd",
another: 122
},
{
id: 2,
value: "asds",
another: 211
}
])
```

I want to reset value from each object. Just value, without affecting another. Thank you :)

EDIT

I want to have this output:

const [items, setItems] = useState([
{
id: 1,
value: "",
another: 122
},
{
id: 2,
value: "",
another: 211
}
])

Comment: a loop using map ?

Comment: Loop your original data and find the correct one, update it and update state using setItems

Comment: loop over the items and modify the object and set the State with modified value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reset the value of item with id equal to 2, you have to write something like this. the *prevItems* will be the previous state of *items*.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
{
id: 1,
value: "asd",
another: 122
},
{
id: 2,
value: "asds",
another: 211
}
])

setItems(prevItems => prevItems.map(prevItem => 
   prevItem.id === 2 ? {...prevItem, value: ""} : prevItem));
```

And if you want to reset all the values, you can write something like this:

```
setItems(prevItems => prevItems.map(prevItem =>
    ({...prevItem, value: ""}));
```